# Saving time in Ruby on Rails to a Postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I have been having an issue getting the right time to be saved in my database.  If I do SELECT NOW() in postgres I will get the right time in EDT.  When I do a Time.now in the ruby console I get the correct time as well.  I can even take what I get from Time.now and manually copy/paste it and save it to the database through psql and it will be right.  The problem is when I try to save the time in code, the time will jump to 3 or 4 hours ahead.

If anyone needs to see exactly what I get from Time.now or SELECT NOW() let me know and I'll post it when I get home.

I'm sure there is something small I'm overlooking, but I cannot figure it out!  I'm guessing this may be a common issue for people setting up Ruby on Rails with postgres.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What time are you trying to capture?

Comment: What does Time.zone.now give you?

Comment: Thu, 15 Mar 2012 22:34:30 UTC +00:00  I guess that is my problem

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 by default saves all the time in database relative in GMT+00:00 time zone. So you will have to set an offset while computing time depending on your timezone. Else, you can change default Activerecord time zone by adding following to `application.rb`

```
 config.time_zone = 'Your time zone' (Example: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
 config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Your time zone' (Example: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```